# how to identify from HttpContext object that requesting application or browser is cookieless?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i identify just from the HttpContext Object that the HttpRequest coming to my application is from a cookieless application or cookieless browser?

Answer (score 2):

If your application is cookieless then maybe on the cookie you **always gets null**, thats means that on the first request that you ask for a cookie you always gets null, but if you set a cookie, then you can not know if the browser keeps it until you ask for the cookie again, and that leads to:
 **if the user did not accept cookies**, then you can only discover this on the first post data, where **you need to compare the cookies before and after the post data** and see if they are the same.

the **HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies** is report faults results  because can not see if the user has disable the cookies on his browser. This is only check the browser if he can handle cookie, but not on real time, but from a static xml data file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your suggested solution does not work in my case. I have implemented a custom session store provider in which i need to identify that the request coming to my website using underline SSP is cookieless or not inside my Session Store provider where i might get mutiple get requests from same browser for same session..i hope you understand the issue.

Comment: @Asoo I have search a lot this mater and if you find some other working solution I will glad to see it. To point out my trick, is to compare the cookie before and after post back data.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies
```

Returns false when browser do not supports cookies.